# Find the size of L1 and L2 cache with C++

Tags: c++, caching

I need to find the size of L1 and L2 cache for an assignment using a c++ simple program in a Windows operating system. I was able to find the size of the L3 cache in 2 different computers by calculating the time it takes to access the elements in an array in increasing sizes. When the jump in time is big, we go from the cache level to the ram level.

How do I figure out the L1 and L2 sizes from here?

The restriction is that I cannot read config or use built in functions to determine the values. I must time read/write operations instead.

Comment: Please don't use "C/C++", there is no such language. Instead tag only the language you're actually programming in. C++ in your case.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Actually, OP's code barely uses any C++, so in a sense he's not wrong... will edit the title according to this comment.

Comment: Issue the CPUID instruction. Then based on what it returns, look up the cache sizes in a pre-generated table of all CPUs you care about. Would be one way.

Comment: At least state the **operating system** that the code should work for. If the architecture isn't implied by that, also state the architecture. For now voted to close as too broad.

Comment: @einpoklum: You should have removed the spammed C tag with you edit. This is clearly C++, not C code (feel free to prove me wrong providing a reference to the C standard specifying the `new` operator). Also using C coding style does not make C++ code C. Identical syntax does not guarantee identical semantics

Comment: This code is insuitable for the job. What if the compiler completely eliminates the loop? It can do this legally, as it is completely irrelevant for the program's output. Plus there are not just caches and main memory (sidenote: caches are RAM, too), but various buffers, etc.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf the code should work in Windows and reliably find the cache sizes regardless on various systems. Also the restriction is that I cannot read config or use built in functions to determine this values. So I must time read/write operations instead.

Comment: @Olaf: replace the `new` and `delete` with `malloc()` and `free()` and it becomes [C code](https://godbolt.org/g/UCbmUi) (upto undefined variables and missing includes.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://www.hpl.hp.com/research/cacti/aca_ch2_cs2.c) would help. It comes from [this website](http://www.hpl.hp.com/research/cacti/) and I came across it through Hennessy and Patterson computer architecture book.

Comment: Who wrote the program? You (then you need to improve your program to avoid UB) or your teacher (then in theory he is wrong)? Are you allowed to improve it? Please **edit your question** to improve it!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch From what I understand the problem is with the way I create the arrays. There is a hint in the assignment that I need to use dynamically created arrays of increasing sizes to test for the L3 cache. Is there another way I could do it?

Answer (score 0):

> I need to find the size of L1 and L2 cache for an assignment using a c/c++ simple program.

In general, **you cannot** (in theory).

Since a standard conforming C11 implementation  (read [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)) don't even need to run on a real computer with caches. And likewise for [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) or C++14 (read [n3337](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/n3337.pdf)).

It could run:

- with people (using a bunch of slaves to run a C program would be unethical, inefficient, slow, but is possible; using for half an hour students in a classroom is an entertaining way of teaching C or C++ - the entire class becomes a C or C++ implementation).
- on a computer without any cache. Today, microcontrollers (like [Arduino](http://arduino.cc/)) can be programmed in C or C++ (and routinely are) and don't have any cache.
- on your favorite x86-64 laptop. You'll better read more about the way Intel and AMD processors deal with cache.
- on something else (eg some [Power9 motherboard](https://www.raptorcs.com/TALOSII/), some [Intel Edison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Edison), some [Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/), some [emulator in your browser](https://bellard.org/jslinux/), etc...). You could have surprises!

> How do I figure out the L1 and L2 sizes from here?

You could look at the generated assembler code (with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compile using `g++ -O1 -fverbose-asm -S` then look into the generated `.s` file), imagine what kind of processor and ISA you have, and make some educated guess (from the measured timings). Avoid asking too strong [optimizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) (since your program probably has [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)).

On many OSes, you might use operating system specific API to query about the processor. On Linux, you could use [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) and use `/proc/cpuinfo`

If you did run your program, benchmark it several times, and gave the timing, you could make an educated guess about cache sizes (but you need to assume that your process has not been scheduled out too often; on a very loaded system, that is not the case; you should avoid [thrashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_(computer_science))).

BTW I guess that under the [as-if rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As-if_rule) **your program might be [optimized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler)** to something you did not think about (see [this](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html)). Notice that using cells inside a `new` allocated array without initializing them is (in principle) [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (or at least [unspecified behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unspecified_behavior)). So I believe a wise enough compiler could optimize your program to the equivalent of some `abort()` (or maybe just keep the `printf`).

Comment: This is true, but it seems to me OP meant to say "Fine the cache size on a typical desktop/laptop PC".

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you explain further what you mean in the last paragraph?

Comment: Probably you are referring to Intel Edison "first" version which had never been available.